# ValueError: Layer "functional_3" expects 2 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow

ValueError: Layer "functional_3" expects 2 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, 224, 224, 3) dtype=uint8>]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi @723_SakshiNagare, If you are passing the data using  tf.data.Dataset as x to tensorflow fit method, it expects both the input and the target in that same Dataset. If you are passing only features not the target it will produce the error. Also Please provide the standalone code to reproduce the issue. Thank You.